# Is there an efficient algorithm for outputting all strings stored in a sorted lexicographically list that are a permutation of an input string?

Tags: java, string, performance, permutation, lexicographic

I would like to find the most efficient algorithm for this problem:
Given a string `str` and a list of strings `lst` that consists of only lowercase English characters and is **sorted lexicographically**, find all the words in `lst` that are a permutation of `str`.

for example:
`str` = "cat", `lst` = {"aca", "acc", "act", "cta", "tac"}

would return: {"act", "cta", "tac"}

I already have an algorithm that doesn't take advantage of the fact that `lst` is lexicographically ordered, and I am looking for the most efficient algorithm that takes advantage of this fact.

My algorithm goes like this:

```
public List<String> getPermutations(String str, List<String> lst){
  List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
  for (String word : lst)
        if (checkPermutation(word, str))
            res.add(word);
  return res;
}


public boolean checkPermutation(String word1, String word2) {
    if (word1.length() != word2.length())
        return false;
    int[] count = new int[26];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < word1.length(); i++) {
        count[word1.charAt(i) - 'a']++;
        count[word2.charAt(i) - 'a']--;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        if (count[i] != 0) {
            return false;
        }
    return true;
}
```

Total runtime is O(NK) where N is the number of strings in `lst`, and k is the length of `str`.

Comment: You may skip elements in the list if they don't start with one of the characters in your starting `str`. But else, I'm not entirely sure if your algorithm could be improved

Comment: And just saying: as homework exercises, such things are great, as you can spend A LOT of time and energy, and learn a lot about different strategies and whatnot. But beware: if we are talking about "real world production" code, then you shouldn't spend a lot of time UNLESS you are already observing a "real" performance issue. Meaning: unless your carefully measured benchmarks show that you aren't "fast enough" (compared to some contract you signed), or you have users complaining about this specific part ...

Comment: there is NO point in sitting down for hours to optimize something to be 1 ms faster in the end

Answer (score 2):

One simple optimisation (that only becomes meaningful for really large data sets, as it doesn't really improve the O(NK):

- put all the characters of your incoming `str` into a Set `strChars`
- now: when iterating the words in your list: fetch the first character of each entry
- if `strChars.contains(charFromListEntry`): check whether it is a permutation
- else: obviously, that list word can't be a permutation

Note: the sorted ordering doesn't help *much* here: because you still have to check the first char of the next string from your list.

There might be *other* checks to avoid the costly `checkPermutation()` run, for example to first compare the lengths of the words: when the list string is shorter than the input string, it obviously can't be a permutation of *all* chars.

But as said, **in the end** you have to iterate over all entries in your list and determine whether an entry is a permutation. There is no way avoiding the corresponding "looping". The only thing you can affect is the cost that occurs *within* your loop.

Finally: if your List of strings would be a Set, then you could "simply" compute all permutations of your incoming `str`, and check for each permutation whether it is contained in that Set. But of course, in order to turn a list into a set, you have to iterate that thing.

Comment: Thanks, that would definitely improve my algorithm. However, I am looking for an optimization that will take advantage of the lexicographic order of the list, causing less calls to checkPermutation(), and even breaking from the loop in some cases. For example: if str ="b" there is no point iterating over the words that are lexicographically larger than "b", and we can break from the list loop.

Comment: The sorting doesn't help you much. Say for example that your string is `adf`.  And your list is `adf, bcd, bhh, cgg` ... sure, you know that the ones starting with "b" can be ignored ... but to know that, you still have to check its first char. The fact that your list is sorted does NOT tell you how many strings are following that COULD be ignored.

Comment: What about this optimization: calculate the char with the maximum value in the input string, and if we encounter a string in the list that starts with a greater char value, we break from the loop. It will reduce the amount of iterations by far.

Comment: @TomerSivan Yes, for specific cases. But in the end, you will encounter words that have x, y, z, or something. As I wrote in my comment to your question: you can find a ton of little optimisaions. Question is: is it really meaningful to do so.

Comment: @GhostCat your last paragraph almost contains the answer. Just drop the Set and take advantage of the list’s sorted nature…

Answer (score 1):

Instead of iterating over the list and checking each element for being a permutation of your string, you can iterate over all permutations of the string and check each presence in the list using *binary search*.

E.g.

```java
public List<String> getPermutations(String str, List<String> lst){
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
    perm(str, (1L << str.length()) - 1, new StringBuilder(), lst, res);
    return res;
}

private void perm(String source, long unused,
                  StringBuilder sb, List<String> lst, List<String> result) {
    if(unused == 0) {
        int i = Collections.binarySearch(lst, sb.toString());
        if(i >= 0) result.add(lst.get(i));
    }
    for(long r = unused, l; (l = Long.highestOneBit(r)) != 0; r-=l) {
        sb.append(source.charAt(Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(l)));
        perm(source, unused & ~l, sb, lst, result);
        sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
    }
}
```

Now, the time complexity is O(K! × log N) which is not necessarily better than the O(NK) of your approach. It heavily depends on the magnitude of K and N. If the string is really short and the list really large, it may have an advantage.

There are a lot of optimizations imaginable. E.g. instead constructing each permutation, followed by a binary search, each recursion step could do a partial search to identify the potential search range for the next step and skip when it’s clear that the permutations can’t be contained. While this could raise the performance significantly, it can’t change the fundamental time complexity, i.e. the worst case.

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution with typical inputs and it is about 10 times faster than my solution, well done!!! The only problem about your solution is that the outputted list 'res' contains duplicates of some of the words, and also contains the original input string if it is presented in the list, which does not need to be in the outputted list. Is it ok for you to fix these little bugs and send me the updated code? that would really help me!!!
Thank you very much.

Comment: This is because your approach generates duplicate permutations for a string with duplicate chars.

Comment: These changes would complicate the algorithm significantly. It would be more practical to just fix the result afterwards, i.e.`res.removeIf(Predicate.not(new HashSet<>()::add));` to remove duplicates and `res.remove(str);` to remove the original string if present.

Comment: Your algorithm has a very good performance on input strings with length smaller than 8, however it is really slow on strings with length bigger than 10 (because 10! becomes a very large number). Does the optimization you suggested in the second paragraph can overcome this performance issue on larger string inputs?

Comment: Not in general. The time complexity doesn’t change. So you might optimize it to work with 10, then the problems will show up with 11. The best you can do, is to only use this variant with small strings and switch to an alternative similar to your original approach (with O(NK) time complexity) for large strings.

Comment: Could you please offer optimizations to my original algorithm that will improve the run time speed (not necessarily the O(NK) worst case)?

Comment: Your code is not bad. Whether there are faster alternatives, depends on the circumstances. 1) how likely are strings with a different size 2) how likely are strings with characters not contained in `str` 3) how likely is a string a permutation or in other words, how big is the average fraction of permutations in the search array.